# Using cdecimal in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to use cdecimal to store monetary values in my database. [SQLAlchemy Doc](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric)

```
import sys
import cdecimal
sys.modules["decimal"] = cdecimal
```

I've connected my PostgreSQL database like so:

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname
```

I've set up the model something like this:

```
class Exchange(Base):
    amount = Column(Numeric)
    ...

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = cdecimal.Decimal(amount)
```

However, whenever I do this, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'cdecimal.Decimal' 'INSERT INTO...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nevermind, it had to do with calling it instead of setting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is working for me please try this

```
import sys 
import cdecimal
sys.modules["decimal"] = cdecimal

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Numeric, Integer, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('mysql://test:test@localhost/test1')
Base = declarative_base()


class Exchange(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'exchange'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Numeric(10,2))

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = cdecimal.Decimal(amount)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


x = Exchange(10.5)
session.add(x)
session.commit()
```

Note: I dont have pgsql in my pc so I tried on mysql.