# cdecimal and SQLAlchemy actually stores `decimal.Decimal`?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, decimal

My django + SQLAlchemy app uses cdecimal instead of the default decimal module.
I followed the instructions on SQLAlchemy's website:

```
import sys
import cdecimal
sys.modules["decimal"] = cdecimal
```

Using the same from a previous stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707278/using-cdecimal-in-sqlalchemy), I am able to add the data to the DB. However, when I retrieve an entry from my table and look at its value, the type of value returned to me is actually `decimal.Decimal` rather than `cdecimal.Decimal`.

How do I tell SQLAlchemy to give me back `cdecimal.Decimal` objects when entries are retrieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is to put this code

```
import sys
import cdecimal
assert "sqlalchemy" not in sys.modules
assert "decimal" not in sys.modules
sys.modules["decimal"] = cdecimal
```

In the manage.py file, rather than the models.py file. This ensures that cdecimal is really replacing decimal from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

SQLAlchemy doesn't have the ability to load the `decimal` module once you've patched it with `cdecimal`.  So in this case you need to make sure you are doing the sys.modules change before SQLalhcemy is installed:

```
import sys
import cdecimal
assert "sqlalchemy" not in sys.modules
assert "decimal" not in sys.modules
sys.modules["decimal"] = cdecimal
```

Edit: also, make sure you're doing `sys.modules["decimal"]` to actually set up the replacement for "decimal".

Comment: thank you - that makes sense, and I looked at sys.modules before `sys.modules["decimal"] = cdecimal` (btw, did you mean that instead of `sys.modules["cdecimal"] = cdecimal`?). This is all happening at the top of my models.py file. Is there another file / anywhere else I need to apply this patch?

Comment: also, I tried running my django app in shell mode. I then made sure that sys.modules["decimal"] points to cdecimal. I inserted fake data into my table, making sure that I use cdecimal. then, when I query for that data and print the type of the decimal column, I get decimal.Decimal instead of cdecimal.Decimal! what might be wrong with my application that could be causing this?

Comment: ah one thing wrong was my copy of your code was populating "cdecimal" and not "decimal" in sys.modules.  I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap `decimal` for `cdecimal` in a more robust way by forcing it to occur before any other code runs. At startup the Python interpreter will read any `.pth` files and execute any `import` statements they contain, allowing us to run code before any program does. I've documented the `cdecimal` swap in more detail on [my blog](http://adamj.eu/tech/2015/06/06/swapping-decimal-for-cdecimal-on-python-2/) - essentially you need to create two files:

Firstly `site-packages/my_patches.pth` which contains:

```
import my_patches
```

Secondly `site-packages/my_patches.py` which contains the swap code:

```
import sys
import cdecimal
# Ensure any import of decimal gets cdecimal instead.
sys.modules['decimal'] = cdecimal
```

Then you shouldn't have a problem with SQLAlchemy since it won't get a chance to run pre-swap.